# Как использовать библиотеку dolfin из fenicsproject?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть код на питоне, который использует библиотеку dolfin (именно так называется). Выполнил установку через "conda" по инструкции. Почему при попытке импорта выдает ошибку?

```
import logging
import os
import dolfin

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-d3f436473ead> in <module>
      5 import logging
      6 import os
----> 7 import dolfin
      8 
      9 from apmod.solver.transient import Transient

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dolfin'
```

Вот то, что было проделано. Скрин с https://github.com/FEniCS/dolfinx/blob/main/README.md#installation
[image: Инструкция по установке]

Comment: [import dolphinx](https://docs.fenicsproject.org/dolfinx/main/python/demos/demo_poisson.html)

Comment: Аналогично. Такой же текст ошибки